# How and Where should I save uploaded User Profile (and related) pictures/videos/files?

Tags: c#, .net, storage

In a WebMatrix web site, where User Profiles are dynamically generated from the Database, where and how should I store user uploaded content?

I don't want this content to be publicly viewable unless the user has chosen make their profile, and uploaded content Publicly viewable.

But I can't just shove it all in a separate directory, since all you need to do is guess the location where such content is stored, and then browse the list of files in that dir. So, should I place it outside my \root directory (I don't think this is possible in some Shared hosting environments), or should I somehow insert this content into a database? (I'm trying to avoid this option as best as I can).

For content like Images and Videos, I was thinking that I should use a trusted Storage provider / image host type service where I would have API access used to store and retrieve these files, and then just store a link to the file uploaded to the file storage host in my database?

Answer (score 2):

You could either

- Store the extra files along the other user details in the database. (you probably want to discuss this with the db admins before implementing your storage like this)
- Put the files on a fileshare your ASP.NET application has access to but that is not accessible from the web.
- Turn of directory browsing and put the files there. "everyone" can't browse all files but it does mean that anyone that has a direct link can download that file without being logged in.

I would go with option 2: Put the files in a directory not directly accessible from the web and channel all downloads through your web app so that you control who can download what.

Comment: thank you. Are there any file share services that would be good for this type of site (i.e. not a personal site) that you could recommend?

Comment: I would just store them on the windows file system :) If you are not going to have *alot* of files it won't be an issue.